# I am trying to run a Rails test using rspec on my webpage, but it gives me errors (Ubuntu)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In my previous identical post I didn't get to solve my problem and didn't get many answers, so I'm reposting my problem to try and get more help.

I am following a tutorial by [Michael Hartl](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#sec-TDD) and in 3.2.1 we are testing the server with:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  describe "Home page" do

    it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      expect(page).to have_content('Sample App')
    end
  end
end
```

When I input "bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb"  in the console I get a bunch of errors shown below:

```
root@KyleBuntu:~/Desktop/Rails/sample_app# bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
/home/verendus/Desktop/Rails/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `require': /home/verendus/Desktop/Rails/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:44: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)
:DSL to config.include Capybara::DSL
       ^
    from /home/verendus/Desktop/Rails/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
    from /home/verendus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

I know that I am supposed to get an error, but in the book the errors that the author received was much shorter and was different. (Link in comments)

I have changed the rspec_helper.rb file to add the Capybara DSL, but I'm not sure if that's the problem and if I did or didn't input it properly. I am also quite new to Rails, Ruby and coding/Linux systems (I am using Ubuntu) in general, so if anything is needed then just ask.

Github link in comments.

Comment: [Proper Error Messages](https://softcover.s3.amazonaws.com/636/ruby_on_rails_tutorial/images/figures/red_failing_spec_4_0.png) | github.com/dasd190/sample_app

Comment: show spec_helper.rb file

Comment: Your question and link saying different errors.. :-)

Comment: https://github.com/dasd190/sample_app/blob/master/spec/spec_helper.rb The link and mine should technically have the same error

Comment: The error shows a problem with line 44 of your spec_helper. Can you include the spec_helper.rb file in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your spec_helper.rb file.

This line

```
:DSL to config.include Capybara::DSL
```

should be erased. Instead, if you want `Capybara::DSL` to be included, you should add

```
config.include Capybara::DSL
```

inside of `RSpec::configure do |config|` block.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to all of this, can I have a play by play?

Comment: I think these actions are atomic enough. Erase one line, add another line.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a comment line in [spec_helper.rb:44](https://github.com/dasd190/sample_app/blob/master/spec/spec_helper.rb#L44) that has been partially deleted and thus uncommented.

```
:DSL to config.include Capybara::DSL
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
```

You may or may not want to actually `config.include Capybara::DSL`, but the `:DSL to` part is what causes the syntax error.

In addition, you have some strange `.` periods on the lines below which likely will cause you some more syntax errors. You may even want to run `rails generate rspec:install` again to regenerate the file completely.